# Histogram Density not 1

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I've got a data-set with 800 numbers from (-12 to -1). I did a simple

```
test <- hist(data),breaks=seq(from=-12, to=0, by=0.5)
```

, because i need equal bar-widths of 0.5

When I now say: `sum(test$density)` it calculates =2

If i but `breaks=seq(from=-12, to=0, by=**1**)`, then it calculates it right / my area under the graph is 1. (And yes, on the plot I also did `PROB=TRUE` -> But these are the wrong numbers on the plot as I stated)

Does anybody have an idea why the BREAKS parameter affect the density?

Comment: If you think of adding up rectangles under the curve, area is width * height. The density value is the height. The width of your bins is determined by the number of breaks. So it's only true that the density values will sum to 1 when your bin widths are exactly 1 (which is rarely the case)

Comment: @MrFlick -> but shouldnt the area under the Histogram be =1 even if I change the length of each bar? / the proportion should go down equaly...
I think I dont really understand it

The excercise was:
Here is your data set. Plot a histogram with the "proportion" on the y-axis instead of the "absolut value" and make sure the area under the histogram is one

Comment: The area is equal to 1. but you calculate the total area by multiplying width * height for each bar. You are ignoring the width if you just calculate sum(density). That's just not how geometry works. Maybe one of the other answers on the duplicate question will make more sense to you. Or if this is for a class, ask your teacher for a better explanation. R is doing the right thing here. Histograms are **not** about proportions. They are attempting to estimate the underlying density function for a distribution. If you want proportions try a bar chart.

Comment: So PROB=TRUE does the job for me then? I never calculated it myselfe but it seems like PROB=TRUE is right then / it tells me the right proportions of an interval